# MSSQL Try Catch Rollback and Conditional RETURN

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON

BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    UPDATE [Members] SET [Count] = [Count] - 1 WHERE [Count] > 0; 
    **return 0 here if this statement updated 0 rows**

    INSERT INTO [Sessions] ([Name], [Etc]) VALUES ('Test', 'Other')

    COMMIT TRANSACTION

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

    RETURN 0

END CATCH

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY(); **only return the identity if the first statement updated 1 row and no exceptions occurred.**
```

With the code above, is there a way to return 0 if the first UPDATE updated no rows? I only want the INDENTITY() if the first UPDATE edits a row and no errors occur. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only read SCOPE_IDENTITY if you actually INSERT
This way, you have one exit point only

```
BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    UPDATE [Members] SET [Count] = [Count] - 1 WHERE [Count] > 0; 
    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 1
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [Sessions] ([Name], [Etc]) VALUES ('Test', 'Other')
        SET @rtn = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    END
        SET @rtn = 0;

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    SELECT @rtn
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END CATCH
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `@@ROWCOUNT` to get the number changed.  This should work:

```
UPDATE [Members] SET [Count] = [Count] - 1 WHERE [Count] > 0; 
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    RETURN;
END;
```

Because no rows are updated, I suppose rolling back the transaction would be equivalent.

To get the identify values inserted, I would recommend that you learn to use the `OUTPUT` clause in `INSERT` (documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)).  This is a good habit to get into, although the syntax is a bit more cumbersome (you have to define a table/table variable to store the inserted values).  It has no race conditions and it allows you return multiple identity values.